# Export the specification and body in a single file

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using SQL Developer 3.0.04 and am trying to export a package. I have 2 questions:

1. Can I export both package specification and body in a single export (resulting in 1 export.sql file)?
2. The export.sql file is somewhat compressed, any way I can have it in text format with linefeeds etc so I can read it better?

Answer (score 9):

In SQL-Developer right click the Package Specification and select `Save Package Spec and Body...` This will generate one file with both the spec and body.

Comment: This is all good and fine but I have issues with encoding. It looks like there is not option to select encoding. All special characters are converted into ?. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of navigating to the package object and doing export there, use \Tools\Database Export to generate a single file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to right click on the package and select : "Save Package Spec And Body"

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Just navigate to package body -> export -> check "Include Dependants"

As a result, export.sql will be generated with package declaration and package body.

Additionally, you will get all DDL of used tables in package extra (you cannot switch it off); this can be treated as advantage or disadvantage of this method.

However, if you plan to export packages and tables anyway, you may take use of the above method, and after that use sql scripts generated by exporting tables+data, that will recreate the tables anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1. Search for the package

[image: Search for the package]

2. Right-click on the package Spec and you can find the option "Save Package Spec and Body". From there, a wizard appears to save the package in SQLformat.

[image: Right click on package spec]